# How to make it so that an EnumProperty is not animatable

Tags: python, animation, interface

I've coded this enum property using this code:

```
class RuleCondition(PropertyGroup):
    data_type: EnumProperty(
        name="Condition Object Type",
        description="The type of data",
        items=[
            (
                RuleIDStrings.OBJECT,
                'Object',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            ),
            (
                RuleIDStrings.MATERIAL,
                'Material',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            )
        ],
    )
...
```

And it shows up like this in the interface:

[image]

Is there a way that I can make it non-animatable so that the little circle next to it allowing for keyframes doesn't show up? I've tried setting the [is_animatable](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Property.html#bpy.types.Property.is_animatable) flag to False:

```
    data_type: EnumProperty(
        name="Condition Object Type",
        description="The type of data",
        items=[
            (
                RuleIDStrings.OBJECT,
                'Object',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            ),
            (
                RuleIDStrings.MATERIAL,
                'Material',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            )
        ],
        is_animatable=False
    )
```

But the EnumProperty can't register when I do that. It also doesn't allow me to use a colon instead of an equals sign (it says "positional argument follows keyword argument"). Any thoughts on how to make it so that this property isn't animatable?

UPDATE: When I pass an empty options parameter as shown below, I get the following error.

```
class RuleCondition(PropertyGroup):
    data_type: EnumProperty(
        name="Condition Object Type",
        description="The type of data",
        items=[
            (
                RuleIDStrings.OBJECT,
                'Object',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            ),
            (
                RuleIDStrings.MATERIAL,
                'Material',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            )
        ],
        options={}
    )
...
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anson/.vscode/extensions/jacqueslucke.blender-development-0.0.17/pythonFiles/include/blender_vscode/operators/addon_update.py", line 27, in execute
    bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module=self.module_name)
  File "/home/anson/Downloads/Software/blender-3.1.0-linux-x64/3.1/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anson/Downloads/Software/blender-3.1.0-linux-x64/3.1/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 387, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "/home/anson/.config/blender/3.1/scripts/addons/Brightaxe/__init__.py", line 112, in register
    _call_globals("register")
  File "/home/anson/.config/blender/3.1/scripts/addons/Brightaxe/__init__.py", line 108, in _call_globals
    getattr(m, attr_name)()
  File "/home/anson/.config/blender/3.1/scripts/addons/Brightaxe/properties/rules_properties.py", line 191, in register
    bpy.utils.register_class(class_to_register)
ValueError: bpy_struct "RuleCondition" registration error: 'data_type' EnumProperty could not register (see previous error)


Sending: {'type': 'enableFailure'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR;** Add `options=set()` as a parameter when defining the EnumProperty to avoid passing the default {'ANIMATABLE'} value.

[`bpy.props.EnumProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) is a function that takes these arguments:

> EnumProperty(items, name="", description="", default=None, options={'ANIMATABLE'}, override=set()
> .. function:: EnumProperty(items, name="", description="", default=None, options={'ANIMATABLE'}, override=set(), tags=set(), update=None, get=None, set=None)

You need to remove the attempt to set `is_animatable` directly and instead pass `options={}` as an argument.  Unless you want to set any options from HIDDEN’, ‘SKIP_SAVE’, ‘ANIMATABLE’, ‘ENUM_FLAG’, ‘LIBRARY_EDITABLE, in which case you pass them in the options set.

```py
    data_type: EnumProperty(
        name="Condition Object Type",
        description="The type of data",
        items=[
            (
                RuleIDStrings.OBJECT,
                'Object',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            ),
            (
                RuleIDStrings.MATERIAL,
                'Material',
                "The condition should be based on an object being present or not"
            )
        ],
        options=set()
    )
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the answer! I tried adding it exactly as you show, but I receive the error "EnumProperty could not register"

Comment: can you paste the entire error callback stack in your answer?

Comment: Okay, I added the whole error stack! :)

Comment: I think you have a problem with `RuleIDStrings` now, rather than with the animatable property, but I'd need to see the code where that's defined.

Comment: Yeah, it could be except for that it registers fine before I add the options. Here's the code for that:

```
class RuleIDStrings():
    """ This class acts as an Enum.
    """
    OBJECT = "OBJECT"
    MATERIAL = "MATERIAL"

    IS = "IS"
    IS_NOT = "IS_NOT"

    SINGLE_MATERIAL = "SINGLE_MATERIAL"
    MATERIAL_GROUP = "MATERIAL_GROUP"

    EXCLUDE_OBJECT = "EXCLUDE_OBJECT"
    FORCE_INCLUDE_OBJECT = ...
```

Comment: Are you calling `bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable` directly?

Comment: It's possible; I'm using Jacques Lucke's VS Code extension for Blender. I'll try it without that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137556/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-anson-savage).